# How to merge common properties in array of Objects using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my data.

```js
[
 {
  "author":
   {
     "id":"101",
     "label:"abc"
   },
   "books":
   {
      "id":"1"
   }
 },
  {
   "author":
   {
     "id":"101",
     "label:"abc"
   },
   "books":
   {
      "id":"2"
   }
  }
]
```

In the above array contains list of objects, first object first property and second object first property values are same any time, but remaining properties values are different from every time. so different properties values are push into one array like , i want to get output like this

Output:-

```js
[
{
   "author":
   {
     "id":"101",
     "label:"abc",
     "books":[
      {"id":"1"},
      {"id":"2"}
      ]
   }
}
]
```

Comment: use snippets to show running code. You did not include efforts so the snippets do not run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Hi Nikola, how to remove first property from every object in array

Answer (score 0):

I can help you out ;) You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and ES6 deep object destructuring assignment for aggregation of data, and `Array.prototype.map` - for generating the desired output:

```
const data = [{author:{id:"101",label:"abc"},books:{id:"1"}},{author:{id:"101",label:"abc"},books:{id:"2"}}];

const dataObj = data.reduce((all, { author: { id: author_id, label }, books: { id: book_id } }) => {

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(author_id)) {
        all[author_id] = { id: author_id, label, books: [] };
    }

    all[author_id].books.push({ id: book_id });

    return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(dataObj).map(k => ( { author: dataObj[k] } ) );

console.log(result);
```